# Storing an encrypted password in an App.Config file

Tags: c#, xml, encryption, app-config

I have built a manual App.Config for an executable being launched from the Windows Task Scheduler. I was hoping to store an encrypted logon and password inside, but DPAPI encrypts using characters that XML considers illegal. CDATA does not mask these and I am wondering if I am overlooking anything that would allow the App.Config XML to contain these.

I have tried CDATA.
I have tried escaping the illegal characters.
I have tried converting the characters to their Ox equivalents.

User logon is jas189

Encrypted looks like this: ì¦fÌ\nCbp:Á!

User password is password

Encrypted looks like this: I@!³J.\"1ùÊö¬

I am hoping for a method to store the encrypted user name and password so that a remote server can log in to do the work. The App.Config will be with the .exe Task Scheduler calls.

Comment: Why not base64 encode it?

Comment: Would using aspnet_regiis to encrypt a section of the app.config file as [outlined here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gaurav/2013/12/15/encrypting-section-of-config-file-using-aspnet_regiis-exe-the-configuration-for-physical-path-web-config-cannot-be-opened/) meet your needs?

Comment: I did try that, but ran into difficulties where the byte array did not include the padding for DPAPI to process. I am encrypting to the 16 byte requirement for DPAPI.

Comment: Make sure that you really need to store a password in config file and there is no other way to do it. It is unsafe and anyone who has access to machine can also access this password after all.

Comment: @itsme86 It might. That was actually the first thing I looked at for the encrypt / decript of the password, but the idea this is being done for would be broken. These applications need to be maintained by non-programmers outside of the code and except for the sFTP server logon and password everything else needs to be editable.

Comment: @Yeldar This isn't a need for encryption as much as obfuscation. Currently, the userID and password are stored as plain text hardcoded into the class. It will be a different group of non-coders maintaining it and the logon and password do not expire and can be hidden.

Comment: Looking at the questions, I realize how much I forgot to include as the description. My company is doing away with custom application development in favor of canned reports in a multi-million dollar shrinkwrap product. Until these executables that move files and pick up or send by sFTP are replaced or moved to a different automation system, they are being quickly thrown into code to be able to eliminate the failing AutoMate product from HelpSystems.

Comment: We have had success scheduling executables from Task Scheduler, but only one developer had already been writing them in C#. I am building static common classes for the other developers to be able to work with and automating processes of my own. A different team of system/analysts without coding skills will maintain these once we are eliminated. They do not need to know the username and password as a remote virtual machine is using to log onto the sFTP portal, so, those are being decrypted (I hope) on the fly as a scheduled process is kicked off.

Comment: They need to be able to change 30+ other fields like file masks, paths, email lists, subjects for success, subjects for failure emails and bodies.

Comment: I'd suggest either using an encrypted config files (as @itsme has suggested).  Just remember that even though everything talks about the connection strings section of the config file, it can be any section (including one that only has the one piece of information you are interested in).  You could also use the same RSA Key Container technology to encrypt/decrypt a secret (say in a JSON file).

Comment: @FlyDog57 The connection string is also hard-coded in plain text within a library. They do not cause a problem here as they are not being moved. The requirement is for everything other than the user name and password for sFTP to be editable by unskilled workers.

Comment: So, create a custom config file section using the key/value config provider (whatever it's called) and encrypt just that section.

Comment: Good idea. I can do that fairly easily and still be able to have every thing else be editable. Put this as an answer so I can try to up arrow it.

Comment: @RossPresser Maybe because that would be like you said an ENCODING and not an ENCRYPTION like the OP asked instead? ANYONE can decode a b64 string, really the worst way in the world to keep your secrets, same level as plain text dare I to say...

Comment: All right, since my reply was deleted for some reason I'll repeat it neutrally: When I spoke of base64 encoding, I meant to encode the encrypted password, in order to get around OP's stated difficulty in storing the encrypted password in his web.config.

Answer (score 2):

Create a specialized config section in your config file:

```
<configSections>
   <section name="localSecrets" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
</configSections>
```

Then add you password to an item in that newly defined section:

```
<localSecrets>
   <add key="Password" value="Your Password Goes here"/>
</localSecrets>
```

Encrypt that one section using the standard encrypted config section mechanism (either using aspnet_regiis, or some other tool you download or create (I'm not a big fan of aspnet_regiis; it works, but it really wants you to encrypt connectionStrings sections in web.config files)).

Then get the data in the (mostly) normal fashion:

```
 var secretSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("localSecrets") as NameValueCollection;
 string secret;
 if (secretSection != null)
 {
     secret = secretSection["Password"]?.ToString();
 }
```

This will work the same way whether the config section is encrypted or not.  This way, everything else in your config file is there in clear-text, the only cipher-text shows up in your custom config section.

Like any other encrypted config section, you need to create, share and properly ACL an RSA Key Container to get this to work.  The docs are pretty clear on how to do this.

Comment: Just so I do not do it again, why was this given a down vote?

Comment: @JimSnyder: It wasn't me.  Questions sure get a lot of downvotes here.  Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Don't know yet, but it made sense enough to find a way to make it work. Diverted to setting up classes for WinSCP and Chilkat for sFTP and email, respectively. It will be a few days before I get back to the App.Config.